# Compiling C# on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, unix

I'm a beginner in programming and I've got a new MacBook Pro. I've successfully installed Xcode but I found it compiles C, C++, Objective-C only, C# not included!

I want to run and compile C# codes. I found a CSharp plugin for Xcode but I couldn't figure it out.

What's the best way to compile C# on Xcode / OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX) or [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) and this introduction to [Xamarin for iOS](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/).